# Will electron create gamma-radiation?

Tags: gamma-rays

If we put cathode rod with enormouse voltage in vacuum between strong magnetic fields pointing down paralel to rod
end then put electron in it with initial speed equal to speed of light and begin circling around cathode, Will electron make gamma -rays according to synchrotron radiation?

Comment: This problem is insufficiently defined. With proper dimensions, it is possible to make gamma rays. However, it's possible that other configurations of this setup do not make gamma rays. More information is required

Comment: As an aside, it is often convention that x-rays are made by electronic transitions, while gamma rays are from nuclear transitions...

Comment: *"with initial speed equal to speed of light"* I'm going to hope that this is hyperbole borne of excitement and sloppy language, but in case it is not I'll reiterate the usual warning: no massive particle every goes exactly the speed of light as seen from any reference frame.

Comment: @dmckee: I agree, saying "equal to the speed of light" is sloppy. 100keV, 1MeV, 10MeV, 100Mev electrons go from A to B at very similar time intervals, (certainly not factors of 10 time difference!).  They're all nearly the speed of light.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jim said, it is possible to create gamma rays, provided that the magnitude of electron's acceleration is high enough for that.